# Count every hit with django-hitcount

Tags: django, hitcounter

Is there a way to make Django hitcount module count every hit? Currently, it counts once for a single IP but I want it to every hit. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding a default setting in settings.py my file.

In my settings.py file, I added the below code

```
# hitcount settings
HITCOUNT_KEEP_HIT_ACTIVE = { 'seconds': 2 }
```

So with this, a hit is kept active for 2 seconds and after this time period, a new hit can be recorded for a user

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check that this [setting](https://django-hitcount.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#hitcount-hits-per-ip-limit) is set to default value.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works after I uttered some default value